# Has any basketball player dived over the edge?

Tags: basketball, collegiate

Watching the 2016 NCAA Men's Championship for March Madness.  They are playing at the NRG Stadium in Houston.  This is a frequent site for the tournament.

This court is raised, so that each sideline and baseline has about 3 feet of court beyond it.  Then it falls steeply, where bench players, cheerleaders, coaches and camera men sit almost eye level with the surface of the court.

Has any basketball player ever dived into the lower level?  In which game did this happen?